# Why does Firefox not open pages?

Tags: firefox

I can't open youtube.com. It tells me: "Server not found", but other sites work correctly. I can open youtube on Windows, but not with Ubuntu. Google.com worked some minutes ago, but now it says:

> Server not found
>   Firefox can't find the server at ipv4.google.com.

I tried to do the steps described on the official Firefox site, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Could you a) link the site and b) split this question into 2 so we can answer them easily.

Answer (score 2):

To fix problem with "Server not found" you should edit nameserver:

1. Open this file

   ```
   gksudo gedit etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
   ```
2. Add to the end of file:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   ```

with one line wrap

What's happen? This nameserver will automatically written in the 
etc/resolv.conf
And I'm not 100% sure what happened.

Comment: @Horo if you're answering your own question 'cause you know how to solve the problem, so you should click to accept the answer. Than the question will be closed and marked as solved.